# Last ever meaning

Tags: grammar, word-choice, sentence-construction, american-english, british-english

I know the meaning of last-ever but just want to confirm with you guys.

meaning: last-ever means “never ever again in the life”

example: this is the last ever drink (means never drink again in life )

am i right in the meaning of “last-ever”?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is correct. It means the last instance of the item it is describing, or, at least, that it is intended to be the last instance of that item. For instance, "this is the last ever monthly product analysis meeting" would mean that you wouldn't be holding any more product analysis meetings on a monthly basis - perhaps because product analysis meetings are no longer needed, or because you're changing the schedule to a weekly basis instead.